# How to get Great_Expectations to work with Spark Dataframes in Apache Spark ValueError: Unrecognized spark type: string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, great-expectations

I have a Apache Spark dataframe which as a 'string' type field. However, Great_Expectations doesn't recognize the field type. I have imported the modules that I think are necessary, but not sure why Great_Expectations doesn't recognize the field

```
import great_expectations as ge
import great_expectations.dataset.sparkdf_dataset
from great_expectations.dataset.sparkdf_dataset import SparkDFDataset
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, BooleanType
```

The following code reads in the csv as a dataframe

```
test = spark.read.csv('abfss://root@adlspretbiukadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/LANDING/customers.csv', inferSchema=True, header=True)
```

The following shows the schema:

```
test.printSchema()
Command executed in 2 sec 64 ms by carlton on 1:53:28 PM, 6/17/21
root
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
```

I think the following line of code creates Great_Expectation dataframe from the above Spark Dataframe

```
test2 = ge.dataset.SparkDFDataset(test)
```

I then code in the following expectation:

```
test2.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type(column='first_name', type_='string')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unrecognized spark type: string
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/great_expectations/data_asset/util.py", line 80, in f
    return self.mthd(obj, *args, **kwargs)
```

Not sure why Great_Expectations cannot recognize the Spark Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do like this:

**INPUT:**

```
test2.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type(column='first_name', type_list["StringType"])
```

**OUTPUT:**  If it is `StringType`

```
{
  "success": true,
  "meta": {},
  "result": {
    "observed_value": "StringType"
  },
  "exception_info": {
    "raised_exception": false,
    "exception_traceback": null,
    "exception_message": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use names like, `StringType`, `LongType`, etc. - the same names as specified in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql.html#data-types). It should be like this:

```py
test2.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type("first_name", "StringType")
```

see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alex Ott, I added the following schema type and added the schema to the dataframe, but I'm still getting the same error:
```schema = StructType([StructField('first_name', StringType(), True)])```
```test = spark.read.csv('abfss://root@adlspretbiukadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/LANDING/customers.csv', schema=schema, header=True)```